# Array Search warning for two dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I've looked trough some (probably not all of them) similar topics regarding searchin arrays but it don't seems to work for me.

I'm not very good with Arrays which is probably the root of my problem.

I'm dynamically creating Array from data that looks like this:

Name | Time (date with hours only) | Some-Other-Columns (at this point I dont care about other columns, only the first two) - below is just an example, data looks more or less like this:

```
Name1 | 05-01-01 04| other values
Name1 | 14-02-03 02| other values
Name1 | 14-02-03 02| other values
Name1 | 14-02-03 03| other values
Name2 | 13-09-09 07| other values
NameX...
```

As You can see the values for Name+Time are not distinct which is the core of problem. For "reasons" I need it that way. I could use separate query to get separate distinct values just for this step - but I want to solve it with what I have and learn in the process.

So as I go trough data row by row I call:
    $member_array[$name][] = $time;

As a result I get:

```
Array
(
[Name1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14-04-26 17
        [1] => 14-04-26 17
    )

[Name2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14-05-01 18
        [1] => 14-05-01 19
        [2] => 14-05-02 00
        [3] => 14-05-02 00
        [4] => 14-05-03 09
        [5] => 14-05-03 13
        [6] => 14-05-03 15
        [7] => 14-05-03 15
    )
```

)

I noticed the values get repeated so I added Array search to check for repeating values inside the $member_array[$name] Array:

```
if(array_search($time,$member_array[$name])===FALSE)
    {
    $member_array[$name][] = $time;
    }
}
```

And it actually works, but then I get this:

Warning: array_search() [function.array-search]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/bud-net/ftp/praca_dyplomowa/ale/members_time.php on line 43

Warning: array_search() [function.array-search]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/bud-net/ftp/praca_dyplomowa/ale/members_time.php on line 43

```
Array
(
[Name1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14-04-26 17
    )

[Name2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14-05-01 18
        [1] => 14-05-01 19
        [2] => 14-05-02 00
        [3] => 14-05-03 09
        [4] => 14-05-03 13
        [5] => 14-05-03 15
    )

)
```

So I assume that when I first call search for a new name (before first value is assigned to $member_array[Name1] and later to $member_array[Name2]) its not yet an Array so PHP is trowing a warning. Now as You can see the results are correct - all repeated values are not added to Array, but I'm trying to get rid of the warning. How should I initialize Array variable to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right the array doesn't exist during the first call. So you have to check whether the array exists and create it if it doesn't.

```
if(!isset($member_array[$name])) { //if the array doesn't exist create it
    $member_array[$name] = array($time);
}
elseif(array_search($time,$member_array[$name])===FALSE) { //if the array does exist search it
        $member_array[$name][] = $time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the array variable before running the first `array_search()` check. Hard to say exactly what to do without seeing the rest of your code, but maybe something like this:

```
if (!isset($member_array[$name]))
    $member_array[$name] = array();
```